# My prefix is a single word

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, rhyme, affix-riddle

Today, my dear fellas, I want you to see,
that there is a whole new riddle by me.

> The word I am seeking is not very long,
> it's part of a show, where connections are strong.

> The prefix is meant to be one single word,
> that's made by cute kitten, I guess you have heard.

> The infix is silent, but still in the name,
> it's commonly used as a block in a game.

> The suffix is old, but still in the stocks.
> If you need replacements, then you shouldn't miss,
> that one day it's over, so put on your socks,
> cause some time this suffix will stop to exist

> One thing is left over, in my administration,
> I'm telling you, the suffix is an abbreviation.

Hint 1:

> The sound of the kitten is not really normal. It's more of a meme, so it is not formal.

Hint 2:

> The show that got mentioned has 6 Seasons here. The 8th, I promise is really quite near. But I'm not american, I have to admit, the country I live in is centered a bit. To make the things easy I'm going to say, thay I'm european, there's better things, but hey.

Hint 3:

> A character who's in the show, is named after the word I want.
>  His name is strange for western ones, now tell me what I mean, below;

Hint 4:

> The unformal sound of the kitten I said,
>  is made when it licks something over and over.
>  When you hear the sound, you will stop being mad,
>  And you feel like you're on a meadow with clover

Hint 5:

> The "Block in a game" is literally,
>  I'm struggling to stay here lyrically.

Hint 6:

> After plenty of days, here comes clue 6: The game that I mean, is based on the ticks. While every game has ticks in it's code, the number per second is 20 they showed. It makes that vegetation can grow on the ground, but also the mobs animation is bound. I'm ending this clue with the material. The block generates under H2O, while I wouldn't put it in my cereal, as it's made of dirt and molten snow. Well this is not entirely true, or else it would just be some kind of goo. It's commonly used for pottery, and this, my dear friends, is almost all for it to be

Hint 7:

> Today I say: "Here comes a new clue!". The show I meant, has many cops, too. It's not surprising, to be fair, some of them are never leaving a chair. The show itself plays in New York, in Brooklyn, where they have neat pork. I'm sorry for these stupid rhymes, but cops like them solve many crimes

I know my rhymes are bad, but all I want to say, is that they aren't so mad, so I guess it's okay

Comment: The only thing i can think of for the prefix based on your hint is rot13(zyrz) but i can't find ANYTHING that would start with that, so that must not be it :/. And about the block part, here's an idea that popped in my head that may help someone else rot13(gur "v" oybpx va grgevf)

Comment: The first one is almost correct ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hear me out here - after Hint 7 I'm pretty darn certain that the intended answer is:

> **[MLEPNOS](https://brooklyn99.fandom.com/wiki/Mlepnos)**, or **MLEP(CLAY)NOS** (the 'clay' is silent).

Allow me to explain...

*The word I am seeking is not very long, it's part of a show, where connections are strong.*

> **MLEP(CLAY)NOS** is the name of a [character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Brooklyn_Nine-Nine_characters) who appears very briefly in Season 1 of (the fantastic) [Brooklyn Nine-Nine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooklyn_Nine-Nine), with a second guest appearance in Season 5. The show revolves around the lives of a team of police officers in Brooklyn, who as time goes on become more and more like a close family ('*connections are strong*'). As per Hint 2, the show is soon to enter its 8th season...
>
>  (Also, as per Hint 3, this is a name but not a common one in Western nations.)

*The prefix is meant to be one single word, that's made by cute kitten, I guess you have heard.*

> '[**MLEP**](https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/comments/7dhal6/mlep/)' is the noise made by a kitten in various internet memes (Hints 1&4).

*The infix is silent, but still in the name, it's commonly used as a block in a game.*

> In the show, the character explains that his name is spelled with a silent "**CLAY**", spelling it as [M-L-E-P-CLAY-N-O-S](https://brooklyn99.fandom.com/wiki/Mlepnos), which causes much confusion. 'Clay' is also [a block type in the game Minecraft](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Clay), which is heavily suggested in Hints 5&6.

*The suffix is old, but still in the stocks. If you need replacements, then you shouldn't miss, that one day it's over, so put on your socks, cause some time this suffix will stop to exist*

> The suffix (which is an abbreviation, as per the next line) is **NOS**. This is most likely intended to stand for [Network Operating System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_operating_system) - a specialised type of operating system which historically allowed a computer to 'implement network capabilities', but which has now largely been superseded by other technologies (computer operating systems now include a networking stack as standard).
>
>  <sup>NB The OP mentions in comments below that their intended interpretation of the acronym 'NOS' was actually '[New old stock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_old_stock)' - stock of merchandise that has never been sold and remains in its original packaging. This term is common in the auction and retail sectors, and the wording chosen by the OP in the riddle is a faithful representation of this - for once it seems I was wrong to assume my default PSE riddle position of "if a computing term fits, that's probably the intended meaning"...!</sup>

Altogether, this gives us the obscure name we've been looking for over the past 12 months. Now go watch the show, because it's excellent!

Comment: Great! The only thing that is wrong was "Nos", which stood for "New old stock", but it still worked, so hey!

Answer (score 5):

I think the word is

> **purebred**

The word I am seeking is not very long, it's part of a show, where connections are strong.

> Conformation/breed shows

The prefix is meant to be one single word, that's made by cute kitten, I guess you have heard.

> A kitten purrs

The infix is silent, but still in the name, it's commonly used as a block in one game.

> REB or rebounds, which (I think) is awarded when a player blocks another one from scoring

The suffix is old, but still in the stocks. If you need replacements, then you shouldn't miss, that one day it's over, so put on your socks, cause some time this suffix will stop to exist

> I'm not so sure about this one but this could refer to the Sun (or *red* giant)

One thing is left over, in my administration, I'm telling you, the suffix is an abbreviation.

> red. is short for redaction

Comment: You're not quite correct on the definition for your infix. Still a nice answer, IMO.